# video-js youtube git example, files not found

Tags: html, video.js

I'm trying to use the `videojs-youtube` https://github.com/videojs/videojs-youtube. I have downloaded the entire git repo and
I'm running the file `examples/simple.html`, but I keep getting errors and I do not know how to fix them.

As to I cannot locate the file `../node_modules/video.js/dist/video.js` anywhere on the folders.

[image]

Comment: The errors make it look like you never ran `npm install`. Run that in the same directory as package.json (root of the repo) to install all the dependencies, which will go into `node_modules`.

Comment: how do we run `npm install`? I have never done this before.

Comment: Do I run this in `cmd`? I tried that but I get `npm` not recognised

Comment: Do you have NPM installed? That would definitely be a prerequisite... [https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm](https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this commands and everything worked for me:

- Open a cmd, in windows write cmd in search bar
- You need to go through a folder where you want to be your app
  use `cd desktop` command
- Add the command `git clone https://github.com/videojs/videojs-youtube.git`
  the link is the GitHub link of the app
- The app will be downloaded in your desktop then go inside the app folder with 
  `cd videojs-youtube`
- Now you can run the `npm install` and open the html file in browser that had you opened before

Comment: I tried that but I get `'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Then you need to install node.js. Go to this link https://nodejs.org/en/download/ and download the setup, follow the steps and after you have installed the node use this commands `node -v` and `npm -v` to see the version of node and npm.